# Vaadin 23 issue with production mode using spring boot with gradle task bootJar

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, jar, vaadin

I'm trying to create an executable jar file. For this project I am using gradle.
I am building executable jar file using gradle task "**bootJar**".
Unfortunately after starting my jar file like this:
`java -jar -Dvaadin.productionMode=true /Users/fluento/IdeaProjects/respinewsbackend/build/libs/respinews.jar`

or:

`java -jar /Users/fluento/IdeaProjects/respinewsbackend/build/libs/respinews.jar`

this error occurs in console:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder '/home/fluento/StudioProjects/respinewsbackend'. Build project in production mode instead, see https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/production/overview`

As stated below I have 'spring.profiles.active=prod' in my application.properties.file.

Please tell me what is wrong here. 
Running from IntelliJ Idea in development mode works fine.

**Error from console:**

```
Powered by Spring Boot 2.7.0
2022-05-20 17:10:35.935 ERROR 63143 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.7.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.7.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at pl.respinews.jvmbackend.App$Companion.main(App.kt:50) ~[classes!/:na]
    at pl.respinews.jvmbackend.App.main(App.kt) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[respinews.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[respinews.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[respinews.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[respinews.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder '/home/fluento/StudioProjects/respinewsbackend'.
Build project in production mode instead, see https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/production/overview
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.AbstractConfigurationFactory.verifyFolderExists(AbstractConfigurationFactory.java:254) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar!/:23.0.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.AbstractConfigurationFactory.getConfigParametersUsingTokenData(AbstractConfigurationFactory.java:117) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar!/:23.0.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DefaultApplicationConfigurationFactory.create(DefaultApplicationConfigurationFactory.java:121) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar!/:23.0.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:67) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar!/:23.0.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar!/:23.0.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:50) ~[flow-server-23.0.7.jar!/:23.0.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener.failFastContextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:543) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.7.jar!/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:187) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.7.jar!/:na]
    ... 50 common frames omitted

2022-05-20 17:10:35.936 ERROR 63143 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-05-20 17:10:35.937 ERROR 63143 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-05-20 17:10:36.017 ERROR 63143 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at pl.respinews.jvmbackend.App$Companion.main(App.kt:50) ~[classes!/:na]
    at pl.respinews.jvmbackend.App.main(App.kt) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[respinews.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[respinews.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[respinews.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[respinews.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/:2.7.0]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

**application-dev.properties:**

```
server.port=8080
server.ssl.enabled=false
spring.application.name=AppName
vaadin.productionMode=false
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=false
vaadin.compatibilityMode=false
```

**application-prod.properties:**

```
server.port=8080
server.ssl.enabled=false
spring.application.name=AppName
vaadin.productionMode=true
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true
vaadin.compatibilityMode=false
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "application"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'com.vaadin' version '23.0.9'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "${kotlinVersion}"
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

group = 'pl.respinews'
version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons"
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
}

ext {
    set('vaadinVersion', "23.0.9")
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.6.7'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader:2.6.7'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:23.0.9'
    runtimeOnly 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation group: 'org.sql2o', name: 'sql2o', version: '1.6.0'
//  implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.0.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.7'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.212'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.4'

    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.19'
    implementation 'de.mkammerer:argon2-jvm:2.11'
    implementation("com.rfksystems:blake2b:1.0.0")
//    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:2.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.10'
    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'

    implementation('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1')
    implementation('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.6.1')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.21'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5',
            // Uncomment the next line if you want to use RSASSA-PSS (PS256, PS384, PS512) algorithms:
            //'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60',
            'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5' // or 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-gson:0.11.2' for gson

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2'

    //https://codecouple.pl/2017/01/07/9-spring-boot-swagger2-dokumentujemy-api/
//  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
//  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.6.8'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
    implementation 'com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov:bucket4j-core:7.5.0'

    implementation 'com.github.oshi:oshi-core:6.1.6'
    implementation 'org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2'

    implementation 'org.vaadin.miki:superfields:0.13.0'
//    implementation 'org.vaadin:tinymce-for-flow:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.wontlost:ckeditor-vaadin:2.3.4'
//    implementation 'org.vaadin.addons:vaadin-wrapper-for-tinymce:5.1'
//    implementation 'org.vaadin.klaudeta:quill-editor:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.gregwhitaker:roboto-springboot:0.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("pl.respinews.jvmbackend.App")
}

vaadin {
    pnpmEnable = true

    generateBundle(true)
    optimizeBundle(true)
    vaadinPrepareFrontend
    vaadinBuildFrontend
}

jar {
//    archivesBaseName = archivesBaseName + '-' + archiveVersion
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }

}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = true
    archiveFileName = 'respinews.jar'
    archiveBaseName.set('respinews')
    mainClassName = 'pl.respinews.jvmbackend.AppKt'
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Do you find a solution for this? I have the same problem in Vaadin 24.1.

Comment: @Ben - no solution, Vaadin team does not care about user problems. Im stuck with version 23.

Answer (score 1):

The production profile to build your application isn't read from your active spring boot profile. Please follow the official guide to get up and running: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/guide/start/gradle/#production

Enabling Vaadin production mode through build.gradle:

```
vaadin {
   productionMode = true
}
```

Comment: it is. I have a special method which does that for me.

Comment: Well. Your special method is faulty then. The error message states exactly that it isn't run in production mode.

Comment: works flawlessly. Problem lied somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

As @Knoobie pointed out, you don't simply "turn on" production mode for Vaadin. You need to build the jar with the production profile instead, and then, executing it in the same way you have been doing, should work fine.

Adding the productionMode to your .gradle file should do the trick, as explained [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/guide/start/gradle#production).

```
vaadin {
    pnpmEnable = true
    productionMode = true
    generateBundle(true)
    optimizeBundle(true)
    vaadinPrepareFrontend
    vaadinBuildFrontend
}
```